# Increment Object and Append to List Python

Tags: python, json, loops

I have a simple problem, but being new to Python and struggling a bit with implementation. I want to output an array of objects which have values that increment by ten, as well as a specific value that's a function of the `inflect` package. Here's an example output:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "one-yards",
      "shape": "rect",
      "coords": [166, 686.5, 174, 36.5],
      "opacity": 0.25,
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "two-yards",
      "shape": "rect",
      "coords": [178, 686.5, 185, 36.5],
      "opacity": 0.25,
    }
]
```

Note that in `coords`, the first and third entry increment by 10 and 12, while the `name` variable is basically an implemention of an `id` to text, so I can use the `inflect` package. I would like to generate 10 objects and append them to the list, here's my code:

```
import inflect as inf

converter = inf.engine()


def generate_objects(id, start_x, start_y, inc_x, inc_y):
    objects = []
    for yard in range(100):
        id += 1
        start_x += inc_x
        start_y += inc_y
        id_string = converter.number_to_words(id)
        object = "{id: " + id + ", name: "+id_string+ "-yards" + ", shape: rect, " + \
            "coords: " + [start_x, 686.5, start_y, 36.5]+", opacity:0.25}"
        objects.append(object)
        return objects


print(generate_objects(1, 166, 174, 10))
```

Here is the output error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "number_text.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(generate_objects(1, 166, 174, 10))
  File "number_text.py", line 12, in generate_objects
    object = "{id: " + str(id) + ", name: "+id_string+", shape: rect, " + \
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

I have tried wrapping the `int`s in `str(id)` for instance with no luck.

Comment: "I have tried wrapping the ints in str(id) for instance with no luck." I don't understand why you would try this, after reading `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`. See where it says `not "list"` in parentheses? Notice how it *doesn't* say `not "int"`? Therefore, the problem is not that there is an `int` in the concatenation; the problem is that there is a `list` in the concatenation. So, *look at the code in question*. Do you see where there is a list?

Comment: However, you should **not try to use string-building techniques** to create a JSON output. You should build structured data using `list`s and `dict`s, and then use the standard library `json` module to produce the output. You would know this if you had tried, for example, putting `python json tutorial` into a search engine first.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is in the error code.
`TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`

The issue is on the line defining `object`

```
object = "... " + [some list] + "..."
#to fix it, you could do
object = "... " + "[some list]" + "..."
```

If you try the above you would notice that the outcome is probably not what you want because what you want as a list will exist as a non-mutable string.

Hence what you should do instead is make a `dict` with the respective keys and values that you want

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I have used the `json` library and successfully solved this.